# Branch coverage in a java super class which is an abstract class

Tags: java, unit-testing, sonarqube, cobertura

How do I solve a cobertura branch coverage issue which is being reflected in a concrete method of an abstract class.

In the below snippet the equals method of the abstract class Currency contains a part where there is a check for the variables SID and Ab which comes after the condition 
if (getClass() != obj.getClass()).
This part never gets covered

```
     @Override      
     public boolean equals(Object obj) {
         if (this == obj)
             return true;
         if (obj == null)
             return false;
         if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
             return false;
         if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
             return false;
         final Currency other = (Currency) obj;
         if (this.getAb() == null) {
             if (other.Ab() != null)
                 return false;
         } else if (!this.getAb().equals(other.getAb()))
             return false;
         if (this.getSID() < 1 || (this.getSID() != other.getSID()))
             return false;
         return true;
         }
```

I tried to cover these variables in the test class using the below method but it still doesn't get covered:

Test class:

```
    Currency currency = new Currency() {
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            return super.equals(obj);
        }
    };

   Currency currency1 = new Currency() {
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            return super.equals(obj);
        }
    };      

    currency.setAb("SE3421");
    currency1.setAb("SE3421");
    assertFalse(currency.equals(currency1));
    assertTrue((currency1.getAb()).equals(currency.getAb()));
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a new test method, such as this.

```
@test
public void test_equals() {
  Currency currency = new Currency() {    };
  assertFalse(currency.equals(new String()));
}
```

One other comment: you should really implement the hashCode method as well.

In hashCode() it says: If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result. If you only override equals() and not hashCode() your class violates this contract

Comment: because of this contract the OP might review the (generic) implementation of `equals` in a super class at all...

Comment: Will mockito help in this situation or it can be done by overriding the hashcode method inside the currency implementation written inside the test class?